# Closed form for $\frac2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{t^2+r^2-2tr\cos(\alpha)}\,\mathrm d\alpha$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Does the following integration have an explicit solution?

Thanks a ton for the help.

Best,
Ruinan

$$\dfrac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{t^2+r^2-2tr\cos(\alpha)}\,\mathrm  d\alpha$$

Comment: As far as I remember, a similar expression appears in dipole problems in physics. I recall that we could not solve it analytically, only by using asimptotic  approximations (e.g. r >> t).

Comment: If you consider the elliptic integral of the second kind to be "explicit" (and I don't see why not), then the answer is yes.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B2%2FPi%2ASqrt%5Bt%5E2+%2B+r%5E2+-+2%2At%2Ar%2ACos%5Ba%5D%5D%2C+a%5D) reference.

Comment: Thanks everyone and @J.W.Perry special thanks for the WA link

Answer (score 0):

If you want qualitative answer when $r \approx t$ you can proceed as follows:

First normalize the lengths so that $t=1$.
The integral becomes
$$
I(r)=\int _0 ^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1+{r}^{2} -2\,r\,{\cos}\left( \theta \right) } ~d\theta
$$
When $r=1$, using half angle formula we get
$$
2 \int _0 ^{\pi/2} \sin(\theta/2) ~d\theta = 4 -2 \sqrt{2}
$$
Differentiating $I(r)$
$$ \frac{d I(r)}{dr}=
\int_0 ^{\pi/2} \frac{r-{\cos}\left( \theta\right) }{\sqrt{1+{r}^{2} -2\,r\,{\cos}\left( \theta \right) }} ~d\theta
$$
Substituting $r=1$ we get
$$ \left. \frac{d I(r)}{dr}\right|_{r=1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\int_0 ^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)} ~d\theta = 2-\sqrt{2}
$$
The Taylor series for the integral is
$$I(r) \approx 4 - 2\sqrt{2} +(2-\sqrt{2})(r-1)$$

Putting t back we get
$$I(r) \approx t ~\left(4 - 2\sqrt{2} +(2-\sqrt{2})(r/t-1)\right) = (2-\sqrt(2)) (t+r)$$
and the final answer is
$$
\hbox{answer} ~\approx~ \frac{4-2\sqrt{2}}{\pi} (t+r)
$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\root{t^{2} + r^{2} - 2tr\cos\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd\alpha
=
{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\root{t^{2} + r^{2} - 2tr\bracks{1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2}}}\,\dd\alpha
\\[3mm]&=
{2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\root{\pars{t - r}^{2} + 4tr\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2}}\,\dd\alpha
=
{2 \over \pi}\,\verts{t - r}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\root{1 + {4tr \over \pars{t - r}^{2}}\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha \over 2}}\,\dd\alpha
\\[3mm]&=
{4 \over \pi}\,\verts{t - r}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\root{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd\alpha
\quad\mbox{where}\quad k^{2} = -\,{4tr \over \pars{t - r}^{2}}
\end{align}

> $$
> {2 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
> \root{t^{2} + r^{2} - 2tr\cos\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd\alpha
> =
> {4 \over \pi}\,\verts{t - r}\,
> {\rm E}\pars{{\pi \over 4},k}
> =
> {4 \over \pi}\,\verts{t - r}\,
> {\rm E}\pars{{\pi \over 4},{2\root{-tr} \over \verts{t - r}}}
> $$
> where $\ds{\quad{\rm E}\pars{\varphi,k} \equiv \int_{0}^{\varphi}\root{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\alpha}}\,\dd\alpha\quad}$ is the
> $\it\mbox{Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind}$.